# Flask with self-signed Certificate not communicating via TLS

Tags: flask, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I wanted to set up a small Flask backend, which is responding via TLS. First, I wanted to try out a self-signed certificate, whereas I oriented myself around the available online tutorials. For this, I first created the Certificate and the corresponding private key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

Now I simply added the file paths to the Flask app init function:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(ssl_context=('cert.pem','key.pem'))
```

#### Issue

I am able to request the application via HTTPS, but when inspecting the *loopback* with Wireshark, I find the unexpected protocol *Radio Signal Link* (RSL), instead of TLS. *See in the following screenshot.*
[image]

#### Question

Is there a problem with the certification file, or is this standard behavior when running on the *localhost*? My guess is that Wireshark misinterprets the packets sent, but I hope you guys can help me with this. I can provide the packets if needed.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: How do you even know that packet is from one of the processes involved in the connection?

Comment: *"I am able to request the application via HTTPS"* - which means it works, contrary to your claim that *"not communicating via TLS"*. The problem instead is that you did not set wireshark to decode traffic on port 5000 as TLS.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (Find a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789179/tcp-protocol-instead-of-ssl-tls-in-wireshark))